# Запятая перед «чем»

Tags: пунктуация, спп

**Но важно знать, чем лечить грипп, если появилось недомогание.**

Необходима ли запятая перед словом «чем»?

Answer (score 1):

**Но важно знать, чем лечить грипп.**

Это сложноподчиненое предложение, "Чем лечить грипп" — придаточное предложение, *что* — союзное слово. Придаточные предложения отделяются от главного запятыми.